# Pandas sorting, python CSV, using the position of a given value

Tags: python, pandas

'I'm living a little gram in the code.

I have a csv that has headers that don't always arrive with the same name.

`id, casa, data de entrada, hora` another time `id, casa, data, hora`

This csv has different versions and each version is distributed in a similar but not the same way, exe: `id, data, casa, hora` the date column can be in another position.

Having said that, I created:

contends of file1.csv

```
['1', '9992222', '123', '9912', '909', '2021-05-06', '10050', 'Test INICIAL','KG'],
['1', '9992222', '333', '9912', '909', '2021-04-03', '10052', 'Test2 INICIAL','KG'],
['1', '9992222', '143', '9912', '909', '2021-02-04', '10053', 'Test3 INICIAL','KG'],
['1', '9992222', '883', '9912', '909', '2021-03-01', '10054', 'Test5 INICIAL','KG'],


    with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:

    f.readline()
    r = f.__next__()
    a = r.split(';')
    for x in a:
        if "-" in x:
            at = x.split('-')
            ano = len(at[0])
            mes = len(at[1])
            dia = len(at[2])
            if ano == 4 and mes == 2 and dia == 2:
                posicao = a.index(x)

                dados = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
                lista = list(dados)
                lista_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=lambda dado: int(posicao), reverse=False)

                for l in lista_ordenada:
                    print(l)
```

My doubt, I can do an ordering using the date but as can be seen I'm taking the position where the standard date is in the csv and from the position use the content to order the csv?

Comment: Does the date header always begin with `data`?

Comment: Yes, is necessary starting for data.

Comment: Then instead of looping over the first row looking for a value that contains `-`, loop over the header looking for a value beginning with `data`. That will be the date column number.

Comment: What is the position of the date column I can find, what's giving a problem is sorting a date column by the position where it is.

I have position 5 as a return in my code, position 5  is where the first date is, I need to get the value of the position and with that value order.